# stop the_permalink printing and save as variable?

Tags: permalinks, variables

Is there a way i can get the_permalink as a variable? I need to build an info window with it but it wont appear in the $infoWindow variable...

```
<?
    $link = the_permalink($post->ID); // prints out into html
    $infoWindow = '<div><h2><a href="'.$link.'">'.$post->post_title.'</a></h2></div>';
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    marker = [<?=$v_latitude?>, <?=$v_longitude?>,"",'<?=$infoWindow?>'];
    locations.push(marker);
</script>
```

best, Dc

Answer (score 4):

Use `get_permalink()` instead. ([Codex ref](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink).)

Per the WordPress function-naming convention, most functions have two forms: `the_*()` and `get_*()`; the `the_*()` functions will *print* the output, and the `get_*()` functions will *return* the output.